# How to test custom Polymer expressions?

Tags: javascript, testing, polymer, mocha.js, web-component

How to test custom Polymer expressions? An example of the expression below.

```
PolymerExpressions.prototype.uppercase = function(input) {
  return input.toUpperCase();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the “proper” way, and the following is definitely not the best. But this approach works for me:

```
<ul>
  <template repeat="{{ t in testdata | uppercase }}">
    <li>{{ t }}</li>
  </template>
</ul>

...
PolymerExpressions.prototype.uppercase = function(input) {
  return input.toUpperCase();
};
Polymer({
  testdata: ['all_lower', 'First_upper', 'ALL_UPPER', 'with space', '0123']
...
})
```

`testdata` contains all the testcases. Now one might use her preferred test suite to check whether the expected output is correct.